# Is it possible to concatenate sounds?

Tags: sound

I used to be able to make a `Table` of `ListWaveform` objects, and `Export` them; `Export` would automatically concatenate the sounds.  This no longer works.  Is there a way to concatenate sound objects?

Comment: Maybe related thread: [Manipulating a continuous stream of sounds](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5304/89).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply put the results in a list and apply `Sound` to the list.  An example taken [from the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sound.html):

```
Sound[{Play[Sin[1000 t (1 + t^2)], {t, 0, .2}], Play[Sin[500 t (1 + t^3)], {t, 0, .5}]}]
```

You can then export this `Sound` object.