# How can I emit a sound only during a mouseover?

Tags: dynamic, sound

Emitting a constant sound or note (no interruptions) for a fixed duration is easy, but a dynamic duration, not so easy.

Comment: Is this related? I mean the core method given by @SimonWoods. The locator can be easily transformed to MouseOver. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/manipulating-a-continuous-stream-of-sounds

Comment: Yes, thanks @vitalykaurov. I think it is related but it still does not generate a perfectly constant sound (free of quick pauses) for a dynamic amount of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this satisfactory?

```
EventHandler[
 Framed@"Play flute",
 {"MouseEntered" :> EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote["C", 10*^10, "Flute"]],
  "MouseExited" :> EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote[SoundVolume -> 0]] }]
```

Comment: we answered a couple of seconds apart... although your continuous notion is much larger than mine...

Comment: @P.Fonseca, hehe, that's right

Comment: I don't get any sound from this on v7; before I try to debug, any idea why?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, no. If EmitSound run separately works, I would test those events with a `Print`

Comment: `"MouseEntered"` and `"MouseExited"` are apparently not recognized in version 7.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this:

```
Mouseover[off,Dynamic[Refresh[EmitSound[Play[Sin[700 t + 25 t Sin[350 t]], {t, 0, 1}]],
UpdateInterval -> 1]; on]]
```

**UPDATE - re-edited**

For a "continuous" sound

```
Mouseover[
 Dynamic[EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote["C", 1, "Violin"], SoundVolume -> 0]]; off, 
  UpdateInterval -> 1], 
 Dynamic[EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote["C", 500, "Violin"]]]; on, 
  UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

**UPDATE 2**

Based on @Rojo `EventHandler` code, here's an idea for organizing different sound effects on the same notebook:

with the help of `NotebookDynamicExpression`:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookDynamicExpression :> Dynamic[
   Which[
   inst == "quiet",
   EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote[], SoundVolume -> 0]],
   True,
   EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote[note, 500, inst]]]
   ],
   TrackedSymbols :> {inst}]
]
```

and here is a small interface:

```
notes = {"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B"}; instruments = {"Violin", 
  "Flute", "Piano", "Guitar"};
Grid[Map[EventHandler[
    Framed[#[[2]]], {"MouseEntered" :> {inst = #[[1]]; 
       note = #[[2]];}, "MouseExited" :> {inst = "quiet"}}] &, 
  Table[{i, n}, {i, instruments}, {n, notes}], {2}], 
 ItemSize -> {2, 2}]
```

(sorry for the formatting, I still have troubles with this...)

Comment: This is nice but is not constant, the breaks inbetween are what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Mike I'm still looking for a solution for that...

Comment: @rojo Nice, but I still hear momentary pauses. And did you know UpdateInterval -> 1 is an option to Dynamic, you don't need the Refresh call

Comment: @Mike, that thing you wrote was for me or for Fonseca? I don't here any pauses in mine. Beware if you have Fonseca's output showing too when you try mine, because it updates every second to "shut the sound up", so it would shut mine

Comment: @Rojo Quite right! Your solution has no pauses, so I will accept it, thanks.

Comment: @Mike just to clarify that it was the interaction of both solutions that was creating the pauses (due to the way I forced the quiet sound). But I do think you are better served with the `EventHandler` solution. I've just added an implementation approach based on this.