How to Emit a Feedback Sound when I Mouseover a Certain Cell Style - Stylesheet Solution
I am attempting to build a private stylesheet. One feature I would like to add is sound feedback when students move their mouse over a "Section" style cell.  For example, on an Apple TV, as you move past different movies, you hear an audible click giving the user audio feedback (in addition to visual). I find this extra feedback pleasing.
If I can figure out how to do this in a regular notebook cell, then I think I can figure out how to add it to a stylesheet. I see a function called EmitSound[], which seems like it will help.  I also see Sound Entities, which may already contain a click sound (or something close).
Also, I don't know how to emit the sound of a sound entity. Forgive me, I'm having a hard time figuring out how entities work.
Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9657/how-can-i-emit-a-sound-only-during-a-mouseover?rq=1

I don't think Sound Entities contain any actual sound (making them quite useless, actually ...). Anyhow, you just need to find somewhere (on the internet) a click sound that you like. Download it as a file and use it inside EmitSound. Since the other question already answers how to do this on a hover, I don't see any Mathematica-related question left :)

Yes that related post has the real answer, but here's what the OP wants:
Cell[StyleData["Section"],
 CellMargins->{{27, Inherited}, {10, 30}},
 FontFamily->"Helvetica",
 FontSize->36,
 CellEventActions :>
  {"MouseEntered" :> EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote["C", 10*^10, "Flute"]],
    "MouseExited" :> EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote[SoundVolume -> 0]] },
 MenuSortingValue->10000]

You can get a click sound with an mp3 or do it from scratch like this:
Cell[StyleData["Section"],
 CellEventActions:>{"MouseEntered" :> EmitSound[
     Sound[
      Play[Sin[500 Pi t] Exp[(-5) t^2], {t, 0, 1}]]], "MouseExited" :> EmitSound[
     Sound[
      SoundNote[SoundVolume -> 0]]]}]



Exactly!  Awesome.

If anyone is interested... I posted a quick video of how it looks and sounds here:  https://share.cleanshot.com/N7nvWDY1
