# Lower limit of PointSize and Thickness

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to plot a very large dataset and therefore I need to use very small points or lines. It seems `Thickness` and `Pointsize` has a lower limit. Am I right?

```
po = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10000, 2}];
Graphics[{Thickness[0],Line[#] & /@ ({po[[1 ;; -2]], po[[2 ;;]]}\[Transpose])}]
```

[image: example image]

```
Graphics[{PointSize[0], Point[#] & /@ po}]
```

[image: example image]

Note that `AbsolutePointSize` and `AbsoluteThickness` give similar results.

Comment: Points can't be smaller than one pixel on your screen.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, Therefore one needs to increase the size and play with the resolution?

Comment: This question on *Mathematica*'s limits reminds me of [this older question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35485)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Szabolcs, It seems by increasing the size and change the resolution,

```
Magnify[
  Rasterize[
    Graphics[
      {Thickness[0],Line[#] & /@ ({po[[1 ;; -2]], po[[2 ;;]]}\[Transpose])}, 
       ImageSize -> 10000], 
    ImageResolution -> 100], 0.1]
```

we can find desire fine structure,
[image]

I suggest `Opacity` also may be useful in some case,

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.0251], Thickness[0],Line[#] & /@ ({po[[1 ;; -2]], po[[2 ;;]]}\[Transpose])}]
```

[image]